Generalization of Koszul Cohomology for Wedge Product with a Fixed q-Form: Literature and References?
Let $A$ be a commutative ring. For an odd positive integer $q$ and an integer $p$ in the range $0 \leq p \leq q-1$, consider the cochain complex:
$0 \to \Lambda^p(A^N) \to \Lambda^{p+q}(A^N) \to \cdots \to \Lambda^{p+\lfloor (N-p)/q \rfloor q}(A^N) \to 0$
with the differential $d: \Lambda^n(A^N) \to \Lambda^{n+q}(A^N)$ defined by:
$d(\omega) = C_q \wedge \omega$,
where $C_q$ is a fixed $q$-form in $\Lambda^q(A^N)$.
For $q = 1$, this construction recovers the Koszul cochain complex and its associated Koszul cohomology. I am curious whether the cohomology for larger $q$ (i.e., $q > 1$) has been studied in the literature.
If so, I would appreciate any references, names, or keywords that might help me explore this further. Thank you in advance for any insights or pointers!
